# Why do pointers save memory when you need to create a pointer to point to a variable?

Tags: java, python, c++, c, pointers

I understand that pointers are used to point to the memory address of a variable. Correct me if I'm wrong, doesn't the pointer have it's own memory address as well? Aren't you basically creating another variable that has the same value?

```
int example = 10; // VALUE of example is 10
int *pointer = &example; // pointer is equal to the memory ADDRESS of example
```

Doesn't pointer have it's own memory address as well?
How are pointers more efficient and what would be an example of when pointers are really useful? Thanks so much.

Comment: Wait, does python actually have pointers? Anyways, you tagged 4 different programming languages which each has their own use for pointers (if any). You should chose one. Also, define "efficient": In what sense, compared to what?

Comment: Why do you think that the purpose of pointers is saving memory?

Comment: Ok, I'll make sure I do it differently next time. I meant, How are pointers more memory efficient.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the pointer has its own memory address and takes up some space.

But if you have a choice between having say six objects, or one object and five pointers to it, which do you think is more efficient?

Here's an example:

```
struct bigStruct
{
    char message[1024];
};

void printBigStructDirectly(struct bigStruct s)
{
    // When you call this, the computer makes a copy of bigStruct.
    // Now both "s", and "bs" in the caller, take up 1024 bytes each,
    // so 2048 bytes total.
    printf("%s\n", s.message);
}

void printBigStructWithPointer(struct bigStruct *ps)
{
    // When you call this, the computer only makes a pointer variable.
    // Now "bs" in the caller takes up 1024 bytes, and "ps" here
    // takes 4 or 8 bytes, so 1028 or 1032 bytes total.
    printf("%s\n", ps->message);
}

void test(void)
{
    struct bigStruct bs;
    strcpy(bs.message, "Hello world!");
    printBigStructDirectly(bs);
    printBigStructWithPointer(&bs);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to address the python, java and C++ part of the question. :/

Comment: No, i didnt forget. The question involves pointers and can apply to all languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: whoops, sorry I didnt realize python doesn't use pointers, im just starting out.

Comment: @Scottytwotime Nor does Java

Answer (score 2):

Pointers are more efficient when they point to large blocks of data or large structures. If you pass the address, which is usually 4 or 8 bytes, that is a trivial copy on the stack as opposed to megabytes or gigabytes of potential data.

It is true that a pointer can actually be more data than the value it points to. For instance:

```
int x = 1;
int *y = &x;
```

On a 64-bit system, `y` is actually 8 bytes, pointing to data of only 4 bytes.